# Button moves onClick - Unsure if is JS or HTML issue

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a search button that plays a random sound when pressed. However when the button is pressed it also slightly moves, any ideas why?

[Full Example Here](https://jsfiddle.net/a2t0xjgu/)

```
<body>

<h1>Hello Test Title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis odit, maiores quo minus hic nisi ipsum ullam architecto aut corporis. Consectetur officia reiciendis nostrum quam laborum cupiditate culpa obcaecati eveniet?</p>
```

```js
function playRandomSound() {
let sounds = [
    "randomsound1.mp3",
    "randomsound2.mp3",
    "randomsound3.mp3",
       ];

let soundFile = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];
document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = "<embed src=\"" + soundFile + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
```

```html
<body>

<h1>Hello Test Title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis odit, maiores quo minus hic nisi ipsum ullam architecto aut corporis. Consectetur officia reiciendis nostrum quam laborum cupiditate culpa obcaecati eveniet?</p>




    <div class="input-container">
        <span id='player'></span>
        <button id="searchbutton" class="mainsearchbutton rotate" onclick="playRandomSound();">Search Now</button>
    </div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A aliquid assumenda adipisci dignissimos, hic quaerat nulla magni ducimus optio quidem, quos totam maxime id, reiciendis libero corrupti iure. Alias, quidem!
```

Comment: Issue is the span near the button, on click, the span pushing the button

Comment: (Is it still ten years ago, or why are we still using `embed` instead of an `audio` element?)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the solution below.

Here I added a class `clicked` to the `#player` span, and gave it `float: left` to detach the same from the parent and float above.

So the issue is fixed.

```js
function playRandomSound() {
let sounds = [
    "randomsound1.mp3",
    "randomsound2.mp3",
    "randomsound3.mp3",
       ];

let soundFile = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];
document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = "<embed src=\"" + soundFile + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
document.getElementById("player").classList.add("clicked");
}
```

```css
#player.clicked {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <span id='player'></span>
  <button id="searchbutton" class="mainsearchbutton rotate" onclick="playRandomSound();">Search Now</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Abin, it works appreicate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just move the `span` to be after the `button`:

```
<div class="input-container">
    <button id="searchbutton" class="mainsearchbutton rotate" onclick="playRandomSound();">Search Now</button>
    <span id='player'></span>
</div>
```